# matplotlib Module not found Erorr in python even though it is in the pip list

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip, package

So, i am using anaconda virtual env.
I installed some packaes and all of the worked perfectly fine expect matplotlib even though if i run `pip list` it appears

The Error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.pyplot'; 'matplotlib' is not a package
```

Comment: This likely means you have a file in your working directory called matplotlib.py

Comment: Thank you Mr. Shores this solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

As Mr. shores suggested tha i have a file called the same name as the package name

Answer (score 0):

conda install -c conda-forge matplotlib Did you tried conda package support?,Because you're in conda environment